# How to install Code::Blocks

Tags: installation, code-blocks

There are many `.deb` files. Which one should I choose to install Code::Blocks?

I have seen an answer of:

1. `wget https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/17.12/Linux/Debian%20stable/codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz`
2. `tar -xf codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz)`
3. `sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb`

I'm having a problem with it.

[image]

I have successfully installed by this method. I just want understand. Kindly explain it, please.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the package that you are trying to install is [codeblocks](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=codeblocks&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and it is available in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Debian. To install codeblocks open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks gcc g++ xterm
```

Optional: Install the [contrib plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26335755/1940850) for Code::Blocks IDE (`sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib`) to enable occurrences highlighting in Code::Blocks.